# Printing an Array of Staff objects with a toString

Tags: java, arrays, object, tostring

I'm having trouble printing out an array of StaffMember objects by utilizing the defined toString method with my driver.  I keep getting a cannot find symbol error and I'm confused as to what I need to replace the staffList with in my driver to make things work out.

This is the part of the question I'm stuck on "Your program should first print all the staff members (use toString() method of the StaffMember class) to the terminal window"

Here is my code (the Staff and StaffMember classes are from the textbook and were not required to be changed for the assignment, so all problems are with my driver).

```
public class Staff
{
  private StaffMember[] staffList;

  public Staff ()
  {
    staffList = new StaffMember[6];

    staffList[0] = new Executive ("Sam", "123 Main Line",
    "555-0469", "123-45-6789", 2423.07);

    staffList[1] = new Employee ("Carla", "456 Off Line", "555-0101",
    "987-65-4321", 1246.15);

    staffList[2] = new Employee ("Woody", "789 Off Rocker", "555-0000",
    "010-20-3040", 1169.23);

    staffList[3] = new Hourly ("Diane", "678 Fifth Ave.",
    "555-0690", "958-47-3625", 10.55);

    staffList[4] = new Volunteer ("Norm", "987 Suds Blvd.",
    "555-8374");

    staffList[5] = new Volunteer ("Cliff", "321 Duds Lane",
    "555-7282");

    ((Executive)staffList[0]).awardBonus (500.00);

    ((Hourly)staffList[3]).addHours (40);
  }

    public void payday ()
    {
      double amount;

      for (int count=0; count < staffList.length; count++)
      {
        System.out.println (staffList[count]);
        amount = staffList[count].pay();

        if (amount == 0.0)
          System.out.println ("Thanks!");
        else
          System.out.println ("Paid: " + amount);
        System.out.println ("-----------------------------------");
      }
    }
 }
```

This is the abstract class:

```
abstract public class StaffMember
{
  protected String name;
  protected String address;
  protected String phone;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor: Sets up this staff member using the specified
// information.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public StaffMember (String eName, String eAddress, String ePhone)
  {
    name = eName;
    address = eAddress;
    phone = ePhone;
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns a string including the basic employee information.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
  {
    String result = "Name: " + name + "\n";
    result += "Address: " + address + "\n";
    result += "Phone: " + phone;
    return result;
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Derived classes must define the pay method for each type of
// employee.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public abstract double pay();
}
```

And this is what I've gotten for a driver so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class EmployeeBinaryList
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < staffList.length; i++)
    System.out.println(staffList[i].toString());
  }
}
```

I've tried various things in place of the staffList and staffList[i], but I just can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks a ton to anyone who can help me

Comment: what is `staffList` in your `EmployeeBinaryList#main`?

Comment: Also `System.out.println(staffList[i]);` is safer than `System.out.println(staffList[i].toString());` as you potentially expose your program to throw a NPE.

Comment: staffList is the name of the array in the Staff class that holds all the staffmember info that I need to print.

Comment: Create an object of Staff class in your main method class i.e. EmployeeBinaryList & then get the stafflist array from the Staff object.

Answer (score 0):

you need to think about scope here. A variables scope is where that variable can be accessed. The easiest way to know the scope of a variable is by the curly braces. a variable is only accessible directly within the braces where it was defined. So, `staffList` is defined in the `staff` class, as such it is only accessible directly in the `staff` class.

you would have to access that variable through an object of the staff class:

`System.out.println(StaffObject.StaffList) //StaffObject would be an object of the Staff class`

however, in this case you also need to look at whether the variable is public or private. Private means it can not be accessed directly outside of its class. so in this case `StaffObject.staffList` would not be accessible outside of the `Staff` class

In order to access that `StaffList` variable you need what's called an `Accessor` method. A method which is public, and allows access to the variable for printing purposes.

so, here's whatcha gotta do:

First off you need an object of the staff class
Then, you need to use that object to access the appropriate Accessor method for printing

take a good look at the code, chances are its all there for a reason.

good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.cisco.staff;
```

public class Staff
{
  private StaffMember[] staffList;

public Staff ()
  {
    staffList = new StaffMember[6];

```
staffList[0] = new Executive ("Sam", "123 Main Line",
"555-0469", "123-45-6789", 2423.07);

staffList[1] = new Employee ("Carla", "456 Off Line", "555-0101",
"987-65-4321", 1246.15);

staffList[2] = new Employee ("Woody", "789 Off Rocker", "555-0000",
"010-20-3040", 1169.23);

staffList[3] = new Hourly ("Diane", "678 Fifth Ave.",
"555-0690", "958-47-3625", 10.55);

staffList[4] = new Volunteer ("Norm", "987 Suds Blvd.",
"555-8374");

staffList[5] = new Volunteer ("Cliff", "321 Duds Lane",
"555-7282");
```

/* ((Executive)staffList[0]).awardBonus (500.00);

```
((Hourly)staffList[3]).addHours (40);*/
```

}

```
public void payday ()
{
  double amount;

  for (int count=0; count < staffList.length; count++)
  {
    System.out.println (staffList[count]);
    amount = staffList[count].pay();

    if (amount == 0.0)
      System.out.println ("Thanks!");
    else
      System.out.println ("Paid: " + amount);
    System.out.println ("-----------------------------------");
  }
}

public StaffMember[] getStaffList() {
    return staffList;
}

public void setStaffList(StaffMember[] staffList) {
    this.staffList = staffList;
}
```

}

> 

```
package com.cisco.staff;
```

abstract public class StaffMember
  {
   protected String name;
   protected String address;
   protected String phone;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Constructor: Sets up this staff member using the specified
  // information.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public StaffMember (String eName, String eAddress, String ePhone)
  {
    name = eName;
    address = eAddress;
    phone = ePhone;
  }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns a string including the basic employee information.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
  {
    String result = "Name: " + name + "\n";
    result += "Address: " + address + "\n";
    result += "Phone: " + phone;
    return result;
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Derived classes must define the pay method for each type of
// employee.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public abstract double pay();
}

```
package com.cisco.staff;
```

import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeBinaryList
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
      Staff staff = new Staff();
      StaffMember[] staffList = staff.getStaffList();
    for (int i = 0; i < staffList.length; i++)
    System.out.println(staffList[i].toString());
  }
}

```
package com.cisco.staff;
```

public class Executive extends StaffMember {
      protected String somestrString;
      protected double somelong;

```
public Executive(String eName, String eAddress, String ePhone, String someString , double pay) {
    super(eName, eAddress, ePhone);
    this.somestrString= someString;
    this.somelong=pay;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Override
public double pay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
package com.cisco.staff;
```

public class Volunteer extends StaffMember {
      protected String somestrString;
      protected double somelong;

```
public Volunteer(String name, String address, String phone) {
    super(name, address, phone);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public double pay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
package com.cisco.staff;

public class Employee extends StaffMember {
  protected String somestrString;
  protected double somelong;

public Employee(String name, String address, String phone,
        String somestrString, double somelong) {
    super(name, address, phone); 
    this.somestrString=somestrString;
    this.somelong=somelong;

}

@Override
public double pay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
package com.cisco.staff;

 public class Hourly extends StaffMember {
  protected String somestrString;
  protected double hourly;

public Hourly(String eName, String eAddress, String ePhone, String somString, double hourly) {
    super(eName, eAddress, ePhone);
    this.somestrString=somString;
    this.hourly=hourly;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public double pay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}